# Is CallerArgumentExpression expected to capture the null-forgiving operator in all cases?

Tags: c#

I just noticed that a guard clause method I wrote did not output the exclamation mark of the expression used.

Here is a simple program that demonstrates:

```
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

Test(null);
Test(null!);

string s = "Test";
Test(s != null! && s.Length > 0);

void Test(object value, [CallerArgumentExpression(nameof(value))] string? expression = null)
{
    Console.WriteLine(expression);
}
```

This outputs:

```
null
null
s != null! && s.Length > 0
```

whereas I expected the second one to be `null!`, as that was what the expression was. I then wrote the third statement, and observed that the exclamation mark inside the expression was preserved.

So is the second line of the output indicative of a bug? If so, where do I report it?

This was tested in C# 10, 11, and 12, compiled using .NET 7 and 8 sdk's.

Comment: I think this is a bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior you're describing in C# seems to be related to how the compiler interprets and passes the expression string to the method. In the case of `null!`, the compiler might be treating the `!` null-forgiving operator as a part of the type hinting or compile-time check, rather than a part of the actual expression to be passed.

In C#, the null-forgiving operator is used to suppress the C# 8 non-nullable reference type warnings. It informs the compiler that the developer guarantees the value is not null, and thus, the compiler does not need to issue a warning. However, when used with `CallerArgumentExpression`, it seems that the compiler might be discarding this operator, as it's more of a compile-time directive than a part of the actual runtime expression.

The behavior with `s != null!` being preserved might be because in this context, `!` is directly associated with an expression (`s != null`) rather than a standalone null literal.

I would suggest you go to the [.NET GitHub repository](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime) and check if the issue has already been reported by someone else. If not, you might create a new issue and await an answer from the core team, as they have better insights of the actuall implementation, than I do.

The .NET team is usually quite responsive.

Comment: I've created an issue for it, [CallerArgumentExpression does not capture null-forgiving operator #96252](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/96252). Will update if a reply appears.